# Google Local Services Ads API

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to use the Node [Google Local Services API](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/src/apis/localservices), which is not documented yet in Google, so not sure if it's working or not yet. Note I used the [PHP API](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Localservices.php) as well, and I got the same results, so do not think it's related to the language. I assume it is working because of [this thread](https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/63308856?hl=en).

This is the code I'm using:

```js
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const localservices = google.localservices('v1');

async function main() {
  //https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    // Scopes can be specified either as an array
    // keyFile: './auth.json',
    // Took scopes from error:
    // 'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error="insufficient_scope", scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/ https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm"',
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords',
      'https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords',
      'https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/',
      'https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm'
    ],
  });
  // Acquire an auth client, and bind it to all future calls
  const authClient = await auth.getClient();
  google.options({auth: authClient});

  // Do the magic
  const res = await localservices.detailedLeadReports.search({
    // Day of month. Must be from 1 to 31 and valid for the year and month, or 0 if specifying a year by itself or a year and month where the day is not significant.
    'endDate.day': 23,
    // Month of year. Must be from 1 to 12, or 0 if specifying a year without a month and day.
    'endDate.month': 9,
    // Year of date. Must be from 1 to 9999, or 0 if specifying a date without a year.
    'endDate.year': 2020,
    // The maximum number of accounts to return. If the page size is unset, page size will default to 1000. Maximum page_size is 10000. Optional.
    pageSize: 1000,
    // The `next_page_token` value returned from a previous request to SearchDetailedLeadReports that indicates where listing should continue. Optional.
    // pageToken: 'placeholder-value',
    // A query string for searching for account reports. Caller must provide a customer id of their MCC account with an associated Gaia Mint that allows read permission on their linked accounts. Search expressions are case insensitive. 
    // Example query: | Query | Description | |-------------------------|-----------------------------------------------| | manager_customer_id:123 | Get Detailed Lead Report for Manager with id | | | 123. | Required.
    query: "| Query | Description | |-------------------------|-----------------------------------------------| |manager_customer_id:111-222-3333 | Get Account Report for Manager with id 111-222-3333. |",
    // Day of month. Must be from 1 to 31 and valid for the year and month, or 0 if specifying a year by itself or a year and month where the day is not significant.
    'startDate.day': 1,
    // Month of year. Must be from 1 to 12, or 0 if specifying a year without a month and day.
    'startDate.month': 1,
    // Year of date. Must be from 1 to 9999, or 0 if specifying a date without a year.
    'startDate.year': 2020
  });
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```js
  {
    ...
    code: 400,
    errors: [
      {
        message: 'Request contains an invalid argument.',
        domain: 'global',
        reason: 'badRequest'
      }
    ]
  }
```

I got the customer id using [this logic](https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/1467498?hl=en).

Comment: did you tried `query: "|manager_customer_id:111-222-3333 | Get Account Report for Manager with id 111-222-3333. |",`?

Comment: I did :( No luck. Also tried with the other query: Detailed Lead Report, and so on, no luck :(

Comment: It's strange it's not working also API reference page is down as well, I did see bug you created hopefully someone will reply to the bug

Comment: Yeah, there's no API reference page. I believe maybe the API doesn't work or I am not sure what I got wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mayrop/236e7ff55a7fb16b9b30437f00a52978) with the complete code that makes it work.

First, the scopes need to look like this:

```js
  const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
    access_type: 'offline',
    // If you only need one scope you can pass it as a string
    // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords'],
  })
```

Then, the query will be:

```
query: 'manager_customer_id:XXXX'
```

Where XXX is the numeric number of the manager customer ID for the MCC account (without any dashes). See logic to get it [here](https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/1467498?hl=en).

For detailed reports, `customer_id` may or may not be provided as well:

```
query: 'manager_customer_id:XXXX;customer_id:YYYY'
```

Comment: The dash removal is what tripped me up!